# What is the difference between these two books on topology by James R. Munkres?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

I've observed that Prof. James R. Munkres has authored the following two books on (basic) topology:

1. TOPOLOGY, 2nd edition 2000
2. TOPOLOGY: A FIRST COURSE, 1975

Although most courses about which info is available over the Internet use the first, there still are some courses where the second one is either the sole textbook or is amongst the books recommended.

So I'm wondering what is the difference in terms of the topics covered between these two books.

Is the second book a subset of the first one?

Or, is the first book the latest edition of the second one?

Are the topics common to the two books have the exact same content, or level of content?

Or else, which book is suitable for which audience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#1 is the second edition of #2. He significantly expanded the algebraic topology section and added some more exercises to the general topology section.